# SharePoint 2013 Remote Blob Storage back to SQL migration error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Tags: 2013, remote-blob-storage

I'm trying to migrate a content database's BLOBs back into SQL Server using PowerShell script. The migrate() process runs for about 20 minutes but then fails with the following error:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Migrate" with "0" argument(s): "Operati
>   on is not valid due to the current state of the object." ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not v
>   alid due to the current state of the object.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundFileFiller.Fill()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBuffer.WaitForIntervalFill(SPInterval i)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPRemoteBlobStorageSettings.MigrateRecordsToStorage(SPStreamRecordType r
>   ecordType, ContentStorage toStorage)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPRemoteBlobStorageSettings.Migrate()
>      at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Excepti
>   on exception)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

Looking at the ULS logs the only extra information I'm given is this:

> Unable to read full interval from database
>
> Background file fill operation caught exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundSqlFileFiller.OnReadComplete(IAsyncResult result)

So the log information doesn't really tell me anything with regard to the file(s) causing the problem.

From the research I've done it's been suggested that the Recycle Bins might need emptied. I've tried that but it still fails. I've also run the RBS Maintainer against the content database but that's not helped either.

Has anyone else seen this error? How do you go about debugging an failing RBS migration like this?

Thanks

EDIT: Following SharePointGoa's good advice I tried to run an Backup-SPSite today. Unfortunately it resulted in the same error after backing up just over 41Gb of the collection:

Here's the command prompt output.....

> VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Backup-SPSite.
>   VERBOSE: Performing operation "Backup-SPSite" on Target
>   "https://sharepoint.mydomain.com/sites/mysite".
>   Could not read configuration for log provider . Default value used.
>   Could not read configuration for log provider . Default value used.
>   Could not read configuration for log provider . Default value used.

Could not read configuration for log provider . Default value us
ed.
Could not read configuration for log provider . Default value
used.
Read Failed: BLOB id:  could not be found on the underlying storage
Read Failed: BLOB id: 171221\1261dc44-72fa-4a78-9458-a54288fd72ca could not be found on the underlying storage
Read Failed: BLOB id:  could not be found on the underlying storage
Read Failed: BLOB id:  could not be found on the underlying storage
Backup-SPSite : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Backup-SPSite -Identity
https://sharepoint.mydomain.com/sites/mysite ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletBackupSite:
   SPCmdletBackupSite) [Backup-SPSite], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupSi
   te

VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Backup-SPSite.
VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Backup-SPSite.

.... and here's the ULS log for the error

The ULS logs show the following:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundFileFiller.Fill()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBuffer.WaitForIntervalFill(SPInterval i)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedFileStream.EnsureOkToRead(SPInterval i)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedFileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteStreamBackup.CopyStreamToWriter(BinaryWriter bw, Stream stm)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteStreamBackup.BackupSqlDataToBinaryWriter(SqlDataReader dr, SPContentDatabase cdb, BinaryWriter bw)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteStreamBackup.Backup(SPContentDatabase cdb, Guid siteId, BinaryWriter bw)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Backup(String filename, Boolean overwrite, Boolean isADMode, Boolean isReadOnlyMode, Boolean hadWriteLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Backup(String strSiteUrl, String strFilename, Boolean bOverwrite, Boolean readOnlyMode, Boolean hadWriteLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupSite.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()

Comment: Which function from RBS Maintainer did you run? Normally this is used to perform automatic garbage collection. You should try to get more information by running operations "ConsistencyCheck" and "ConsistencyCheckForStores" and ConsistencyCheckExtent "complete". Reference here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff943565.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think your RBS is broken

What you can do is, take a site collection backup (take for each site collection if there are many) of your site using `Backup-SPSite` Powershell command and restore it to fresh database using `Restore-SPSite` command. This will move all files stored on RBS back to SQL database.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice SharePointGoa. See my edit in the original question. Unfortunately it hit the same problem. There's x1 site collection in this content database.